# XPath shortest path between element and contains element

Tags: xpath

Let's have this xpath:

```
<div>
   <!-- ... -->
   <div> <!--I want this element-->
      <!-- ... -->
      <sometag>
         <a></a>
      </sometag>
      <!-- ... -->
   </div>
   <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

I have this xpath `//div[.//a]`, which selects both `div`s.

How to write the xpath which selects the nearest `div` of his child(`a`). Without link it by that `sometag`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to locate the `a` elements first and then select *nearest ancestor `div`* from there:

```
//a/ancestor::div[1]
```

**<kbd>[xpathfiddle demo](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/7d7c51d3de13c74199e6b91c522c05f4)</kbd>**

Comment: For reference, note also XPath 3.1 `innermost(//div[.//a])`